# Recursively finding minimum value (no built-ins or loops)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

Below is my code for finding the minimum integer in a nested list. It throws this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

And I know why, but cannot figure out how to solve it. I am not able to use loops or built-in functions besides len, int, str, and append.

```
def min(nest):
    compareNum = nest[0]

    if len(nest) == 1:         
        return nest[0]      

    if compareNum < min(nest[1:]):         
       return compareNum     

    else:         
        return min(nest[1:])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know why? I don’t – can you say? And show your input?

Comment: Can you please include the code that you run to actually get the `TypeError` you show? In the previous comment you mention a `recMin` which doesn't match name nor signature of the implemented `min()` function above.

Comment: Sure sorry my bad --  this is the code I used that gets that error. Any nested list throws this error, however if its just a normal list like [1,2,3], it returns 1 being the lowest value, which is correct:   print(min([[1,2,3],5,6,7,[8,6,4]]))

Comment: You should add an example content of nest. Maybe nest is [[1, 2, 3]] instead of [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: How is this approach recursive?

Comment: @taurus05 Because `min()` calls `min()` in the last line.

Comment: Are you allowed to call `type()` or `isistance()`?

Comment: @pjs isn't min() a python builtin? Is it a good approach to use the names this way?

Comment: @taurus05 I agree it's bad practice to shadow builtins, which is why I changed the names in my answer.

Comment: If you feel that none of the answers below has addressed your issue, can you edit your question to clarify what's missing?  Otherwise, the norm here is to mark one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're restricted to just `len`, `int`, `str`, and `append`, the following seems to work for me.  It even handles empty lists.

```
def is_a_list(input):
    return str(input)[0] == '['

def nested_min(input):
    # if type(input) is list:
    if is_a_list(input):
        length = len(input)
        if length == 0:
            return None
        if length == 1:
            return nested_min(input[0])
        else:
            mid = length // 2
            first = nested_min(input[:mid])
            second = nested_min(input[mid:])
            if first is None:
                return second
            elif second is None:
                return first
            return first if first < second else second
    else:
        return input
```

If you're allowed to use `type()`, use the commented line instead of the uncommented version which uses `is_a_list()`, and remove that helper function.

I'm not a big fan of whittling recursive calls down one-by-one. Instead, this solution splits lists and sublists in half at each iteration, so it should be able to handle very large inputs.  Consider the following test case:

```
from random import randint

rnd_list = [randint(10, 1000000) for _ in range(100000)]
# use builtin min to confirm answer
print("rnd_list minimum is " + str(min(rnd_list)))          
test_list = [42, 17, [99, 100], [rnd_list], [], 10000]
print("nested minimum is " + str(nested_min(test_list)))
```

This produces output such as:

```
rnd_list minimum is 22
nested minimum is 17
```

or

```
rnd_list minimum is 12
nested minimum is 12
```

but exceeds the maximum recursion depth when used with other proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so you're probably going to have to use some try/except blocks for this one then if you can't use built-ins. It's throwing an error because you are trying to treat a nested list element as an integer, so let's make our try/except handle that Type Error:

```
def min(nest):
    # make sure your first element isn't a list
    try:
        compareNum = int(nest[0])
    except TypeError:
        compareNum = min(nest[0])

    if len(nest) == 1:
        return nest[0]

    try:
        if compareNum < min(nest[1:]):
            return compareNum
        else:
            return min(nest[1:])
    except TypeError: # element is a list!!
        min_item = min(nest[0]) # get the min value from that list

        if min_item < compareNum:
            compareNum = min_item # replace if new min is smaller

        return(min(nest[1:]))

nested_list = [[-1523,2],3,-2,[2], [-23,4],[-2234],2,-1000]

print(min(nested_list)) # return -2234
```

Tough one to solve with all of the restrictions!
Hope that helps you out :)

Answer (score 0):

> not able to use loops or built-in functions besides len, int, str, and append

No loops, `len()`, `int()`, nor`.append()`. Just `str()`:

```
def nested_minimum(array):
    if not array:
        return None

    first, *rest = array

    if '[' in str(first):
        first = nested_minimum(first)

    second = nested_minimum(rest)

    return [first, second][first is None or second is not None and second < first]
```

**TEST**

```
nested_list = [[-1523, 2], 3, -2, [2], [-23, 4], [-2234], 2, -1000]  # a la @AndrewGrass
print(nested_minimum(nested_list))

print(nested_minimum([[1, 2, 3], 5, 6, 7, [8, 6, 4]]))

print(nested_minimum([[], 1]))
```

**TEST OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
-2234
1
1
>
```